# Mozilla doesn't displays datepicker input

Tags: browser, laravel

I am using this function to create a date input

```
  public static function date($name, $value = null, $options = array()) {
        $input = '<input type="date" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '"';
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $input .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
        $input .= '>';

        return $input;
    }
```

And then in my view

```
 <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('sgs', Lang::get('messages.sgs').'*', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Helpers\Helper::date('sgs', isset($v->sgs) ? $v->sgs : '' , array(
                                'class' => 'form-control')) 
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
```

In Google Chrome it works, and displays datepicker which is displayed by clicking at a arrow, the problem is with Mozilla Firefox which doesnt displays datepicker and just displays it as a simple input field. Why is happening this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 DatePicker is not supported in Firefox. Therefore, you will need to use some custom DatePicker plugin. You can see this for the compatibility reference:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime